# Guarantee that a document has beed persisted by mongod

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDb guarantee that an document has been persisted to a disk?

I read docs and even "Acknowledged write concern does not confirm that the write operation has persisted to the disk system."
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/

Can any write concern guarantee that a document was saved or not? I can't sleep cuz i dont know about the future of my documents without doing additional find or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo guarantee that with acknowledged write concern AND ENABLED JOURNALING while inserting, information about inserting a document will not be waisted.